# How to debug a failed iTMSTransporter import?

Tags: app-store, metadata, app-store-connect

I'm currently trying to switch to iTMSTransporter to update my iOS app, but it's not working as expected.

I exported the metadata of the current version using the `lookupMetadata` parameter. I already created a new version on iTunes Connect and changed the `metadata.xml` accordingly. I'm adding the What's New section and updating two of screenshots (The logs show that only those screenshots will be uploaded).

Now I'm trying to import the `itmsp` package using `upload`. The package was verified and upload successfully, but the data doesn't show up on iTunes connect.

Using the `status` parameter multiple times you can see the progress of the import which looks like the following:

```
-------------------------Status Info-------------------------
Upload created: 2013-08-18 13:44:01
Upload state:   Import Processing
Upload state id:    2
Content state:  N/A
Content state id:   N/A
```

```
-------------------------Status Info-------------------------
Upload created: 2013-08-18 13:44:01
Upload state:   Import Processing
Upload state id:    6
Content state:  N/A
Content state id:   N/A
```

```
-------------------------Status Info-------------------------
Upload created: 2013-08-18 13:44:01
Upload state:   Import Error
Upload state id:    4
Content state:  N/A
Content state id:   N/A
```

Using an "empty" `metadata.xml` works without problems.

```
-------------------------Status Info-------------------------
Upload created: 2013-08-18 13:16:08
Upload state:   Import Processing
Upload state id:    2
Content state:  N/A
Content state id:   N/A
```

```
-------------------------Status Info-------------------------
Upload created: 2013-08-18 13:16:08
Upload state:   Imported
Upload state id:    3
Content state:  N/A
Content state id:   N/A
```

Is there a way to find the reason for the failed import?

Comment: Importing still fails after uploading the screenshots manually. The tool detects that all screenshots are up-to-date. So I guess the error is somewhere inside the other data.

Comment: Any news on this?! I just got this error and can't find any additional info.

Comment: Same here, any news on it?

Answer (score 0):

I played also a little bit with iTMSTransporter and it seems that you need to re-log to iTunes Connect to see the changes.

Do you also have the right MD5 checksums as well as the file sizes?

If you put the command -o /Users/XXX/Desktop/log you get the whole log of the upload and it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: This is not a display problem. `status` reports that there's some "Import Error". Having the wrong or no checksums in the package will cause the upload to be rejected.